# EF 5.0 without config details

Tags: entity-framework

1. How can we make use EF code first without the below configuration but rather only a DB connection string, just like traditional ADO.net and dataset.
2. How can EF 5.0 reflect underlying table structure at runtime? like ADO.NET dataset.

Configuration:

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: <configSections>    
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>

Comment: @LukeP, its in the question but, the formatting is missing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing code shown above from web.config? Do you get any errors?

The link from comment in your code (EF 4.3) says that the config section is optional. Also on EF 5 RC page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/05/15/ef5-release-candidate-available-on-nuget.aspx code-first walkthrough links to EF 4.2 so maybe it's still valid.

Comment: I can't believe, It is working again. it used to work in 4.1, last night upgraded to 5.0 rc, it was giving error in connection string that it does not understand the key word server or provider...This is better, may be i was having issues with connecting to sql server but the error messages were misleading .

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the second question. Can you explain?

Comment: if we query data "select * from tableXXX", we'll get all columns from underlying data table which it'll populate the same result to an ADO.NET DataSet. if we use a datagrid to connect to this dataset we'll see all columns.  As I can see in EF, we need to define data entity structure in code first, therefore when the underlying data structure is changed, we need to change our EF code first data entity structure and this means we need to recompile, redeploy..etc

Comment: That's because you're using code-first which by definition puts code first. You can configure EF to regenerate database when code changes. If you use database-first approach and utilise EF automated model generation you can easily recreate the the model when the database changes. But none of the above can be done at runtime.

Comment: thanks, hopefully one day, it'll be done at runtime. it is always the case of missing 10%. it like WCF and WCF data service, why not just have one WCF that have both. Great to have you answered.

Answer (score 0):

you can use connection string directly

```
var db = new DbContext("Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
            //instead of 
var db = new DbContext("Name=DBConnectionConfigEntryName");
```